# Decrypting an 'Encrypted' password from ASP.NET 2.0 Membership

Tags: asp.net, .net-2.0, passwords, asp.net-membership, encryption

I have a requirement to decrypt the Encrypted (not Hashed) passwords located in my aspnet_Membership table. In that database I see the Password (Encrypted) and PasswordSalt fields, and I can look at my web.config to find the machinekey > decryptionKey (validation="SHA1" decryption="AES").

*note: I would love to use Hashed password, but for business reasons I need to be able to use the password for a Member, for SSO into and from other remote systems, hence using Encrypted (definitely NOT using Clear - yukky!)*

Given all that, surely there is a way to retrieve the password as Clear, plain and readable text, i.e. decrypted, but I'm having real trouble finding any website, or answer on stackoverflow (and I'm looking at all the "similar questions" and "question with similar titles" here) that explains how this can be done.

I've found the [MembershipProvider.DecryptPassword Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.decryptpassword%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) page, but I still cannot work out how to actually use this in my code. I've also found other pages, via Google, but most example of password decryption don't appear to take the salt and decrytionKey's into account.

Does anyone have a straight forward example of selecting the password, passwordsalt and decryptionkey from their respective locations, and using them to decypt an ASP.NET 2.0 Membership Encrypted password?

Comment: The whole point of SSO is to delegate the authentication and not share login credentials. Your business reasons are skewed.

Comment: I don't know how the MembershipProvider works, but isn't the point of having a salted password that you don't ever really *decrypt* the password, you use whatever the user entered for a password, apply the salt in whatever encryption method, and if the two encrypted result match, you're granted access. I doubt you can actually get the clear text password without using some sort of brute force attack.

Comment: Guys, I appreciate the comments, and while the business logic maybe skewed, the requirement is still in place. The ASP.NET MembershipProvider gives the options of 'Clear', 'Encrypted' and 'Hashed' formats for passwords, suggesting very strongly that 'Encrypted' passwords CAN be decrypted - just finding out how is my question.

Comment: @QMKevin: unless it's *one-way* encryption, which it is. You might have to implement a custom MembershipProvider if you want to implement decryptable passwords. In all honesty though, it's a bad idea.

Comment: @Cory Sorry to disagree (more out of frustration and desire to learn, I promise), but I've read Encrypted passwords can indeed be decrypted, while Hashed cannot. I read that [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx#bucupro_topic11)  Huh, I also just spotted on this link, a method that claims to let you convert an encoded password back to its readable format. Not sure why I didn't see this before.. my Googling skills are assuming it's the weekend, perhaps. Let's hope this works!

Comment: @QmKevin and @Cory - indeed you can encrypt. Cory, a salted password doesn't mean at all you wouldn't decrypt it, it simply means you've attempted to randomize the encryption method more. In the method you mentioned - sure that's one way of doing it, but no different than decrypting and comparing. In either case a plaintext is in memory somewhere. However for hashing of course, the comparison method on a hash is the only option you have - in that case brute forcing is the only way or lookups with a rainbow table.

Comment: @QMKevin is correct. They can be decrypted. @Cory, another word for 'one way encryption' is 'hashing'. The SqlMembershipProvider supports both, and encrypted passwords can be decrypted.

Comment: @QMKevin: Do you need to know the passwords of the users?, or be authenticated as some user? Different things.

Comment: @erickzetta I need to know the actual passwords, albeit for a millisecond in my code (and not written anywhere), and Adam's link in the accept answer gave me the coded I needed to get that :)

Comment: @All: Ok, I've been proven wrong. Thanks for all the clarification!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Create a class that inherits from SqlMembershipProvider and in it you can call the decrypt.

All the code you need for this can be found in [this article by Naveen Kohli](http://www.byteblocks.com/post/2011/05/03/Decrypt-password-in-SqlMembershipProvider.aspx):

> After looking through the code in reflector, I saw that Microsoft
>   providers decrypts in two steps. The encrypted password is actually a
>   Base64 conversion of encrypted data. So first it converts it back from
>   Base64 and then calls DecryptPassword method. I just did the easiest
>   thing. Copied the code from Microsoft implementation, removed all the
>   checks it was doing and then used it. Following class is an example of
>   a class derived form SqlMembershipProvider with a method that just
>   returns me password in clear text for a given encrypted password.
>
> ```
> namespace MembershipPasswordRecover
> {
>     public class NetFourMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
>     {
>         public string GetClearTextPassword(string encryptedPwd)
>         {
>             byte[] encodedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedPwd);
>             byte[] bytes = this.DecryptPassword(encodedPassword);
>             if (bytes == null)
>             {
>                 return null;
>             }
>             return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(bytes, 0x10, bytes.Length - 0x10);
>
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     var passwordManager = new NetFourMembershipProvider();
>     var clearPWd = passwordManager.GetClearTextPassword("encryptedpasswordhere");
>     Console.WriteLine(clearPWd);
> }
> ```

Comment: Can SqlMembershipProvider be accessed in .Net v5?  If not, how can password decrypt be accomplished in .Net v5?

Comment: @MikeW If your goal is to decrypt a password for purposes of moving to Identity Server and .NET 5, then you can write a .NET app in whatever version of .NET SqlMembershipProvider is supported in, obtain the plaintext password using Adam's approach, then pass them along to Identity Server for hashing + salting.