# Decrypt ASP.NET Membership Passwords from Console App

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell, encryption, asp.net-membership

I have an ASP.NET membership database and I need to decrypt the encrypted passwords. I would like to do this via PowerShell or C#. I have the salt, machine key, and the encrypted password string. This is an example of what I have so far but I don't know where the Salt and Machine Key should come into play.

```
try
{
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(pwd);
    data = this.DecryptPassword(data);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   return ex.Message;
   // No machine key?
}
```

Comment: Are the passwords encrypted or hashed? Hashing is "non-reversible," unless you use black hat methods like rainbow tables, dictionary attacks, or brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this has already been answered here :

[Decrypting an 'Encrypted' password from ASP.NET 2.0 Membership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231942/decrypting-an-encrypted-password-from-asp-net-2-0-membership)

Thanks,

Phill

Comment: Awesome! I will check it out